# How can I take out all data from Stack Exchange (a la Google Takeout)?

Tags: support, personal-data, data-dump, data

I hoped this would be a duplicate, but I found none: I would like to have an off-site backup for my Stack Exchange data, much like I have for GitHub and Google for example.

**How, if at all, can I get a data takeout from my Stack Exchange data?**

Now, Q&A data is public anyway, and there are many greppers active already. It would not be lost.

But my motivation is, to be able to show my activity to a potential future employer, with some confidence, that this actually reflects my (profession and private) interest in those topics. This is easy now, **but in case Stack Exchange ceases to exist, I would still have a compiled set of my data ready.**

Comment: The closest thing is probably the [GDPR data export](//stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request). See [Export User Data (GDPR requirement)](/q/388007/4642212), [Dump of my own Stack Exchange content](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/269804/289905), [Where can I download my user data? (GDPR data portability)](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/312325/289905), [What is the easiest way for me to download all my comments across all Stack Exchange sites?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/209040/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon, want to write that as an answer so we can upvote it?